# Android update profile banner using twitter api

Tags: android, twitter

I am using twitter4j for updating profile image. Here is code:

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(builder.build())
                    .getInstance(accessToken);
            File image = new File(
                    Environment
                            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                    "img.jpg");

            twitter.updateProfileImage(image);
```

Besides I need to update twitter profile banner. I founded in java docs that library twitter4j has method `updateProfileBanner(java.io.File image)`. But I can't find it in code. Does anybody know how do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be there, the Twitter interface extends from the UsersResources interface:

http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/UsersResources.html#updateProfileBanner%28java.io.File%29

Are you sure you are using a recent version of Twitter4J?
It definitely is there in version 3.0.3.

Comment: Thank a lot! Before I used twitter4j-core-android-2.2.6. It was my mistake.